# How to set UNNotificationRequest's custom repeat interval?

Tags: ios, swift, local, nsnotificationcenter, unusernotificationcenter

I'm implementing a custom recurrence reminder like default Reminder App. Here I don't to how to set the repeat interval like Trigger on every Nth day/week/month/year i.e., Trigger notification on every 4th day/week/month/year from now.

Here is my implementation for the interval = 1

```
    if type == .daily{                        
        dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date())            
    }else if type == .weekly{
        dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,.weekday], from: Date())
    }else if type == .monthly{
        dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day,.hour, .minute], from: Date())

    }else if type == .yearly{
        dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,.day,.month], from: Date())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, UNNotificationRequest doesn't have interface to set custom repeat intervals for local notifications.

It seems, that there is no stable working solution for your question, but as a workaround, you could try to implement your custom reschedule logic by requesting multiple local notifications (using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`) based on your repeat interval and then rescheduling new notifications every time the app becomes running.

Comment: In my front, I can't use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`. For example, If I set the interval as 17 months. 17th month may contain 29/28/30/31 days. So `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` may not work

Comment: You can use current calendar to get appropriate time interval ```Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 17, to: Date())?.timeIntervalSinceNow```. Also you can use ```autoupdatingCurrentCalendar``` to track calendar changes and reschedule notifications if needed

Comment: What if the user deletes the notification in the notification center. If it is case means we can't reschedule notification right?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said that this is not stable working solution